# Svg created by Angular 2 doesn't scale

Tags: css, svg, angular

It's known that svg-element with `viewbox` should automatically scale to the sizes from styles.

For example, let's take a 200*200 circle and place it into a 100*100 `div`. Before that let's make `svg` to take all `div`'s space. Svg is scaled so that we can see the full circle:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewbox="0 0 200 200">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="99" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Now let's place this markup into Angular 2 component:

```
import {Component, View, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <svg viewbox="0 0 200 200">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="99" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

With the same styles we'll see:

[image: Screenshot]

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?
I need `svg` to scale automatically.

Full example: http://plnkr.co/edit/jNJNJLo8ygVcp9SIVcDx?p=preview

---

It's interesting that if you select this `svg`-element in devtools and run

```
$0.outerHTML = $0.outerHTML
```

the element will get its expected representation.

---

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/532994/178988)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVG is case sensitive. The correct attribute is viewBox rather than viewbox.

Comment: wow, I was losing my mind over this. Thank you.